# Rails server stops after attaching an image with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, server, ruby-on-rails-5

```
def create
        fr = Front.new
        fr.name = params[:name]
        fr.original_image.attach(params[:img]) # If I comment this line the server doesn't stop
        if fr.save
            puts "Got image"

            render_success_data(fr)
        end
    end
```

[After sending a post request with the following parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1exzi.png).
The server actually saves the item and does the linking correctly and also saves the image on the S3 bucket.
[As you can see the model is saved successfuly commited then an AnalyzeJob is starting and the server just stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DnTa.png)

Tried creating a project from scratch again thinking it was some configuration problem but I encountered the same result.
I'm working on Windows 10 so I thought it might be a system incompatibility but I didn't find anything related.

EDITED:
Here is the method [render_success_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aippj.png)

Comment: What does this method `render_success_data(fr)` look like?

Comment: @engineersmnky I edited the question with the method.